# Storage cannot be found from apps, folder /storage/emulated missing

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, sd-card, storage

I installed a custom ROM (CM 12.1, based on Android 5.1.1) on my Galaxy S2 (GT-I9100). Also, I repartitioned the storage using this PIT file: I9100_2.0GB_Sys-05GB_Data-023MB_Preload.

All but the access to the memory (internal and external storage) works fine. Unfortunately it is not possible to write or detect both storage points. The consequence is that apps like the camera, or downloading any content do not work. If I remove the SD card from slot most of these app crashes or display an error message.

However, the SD card is not damaged. I already used it for installing the ROM and it is detected inside the file manager (/storage/sdcard1). Inside the file manager I can create or delete files and folders, too.

The problem seems to be a missing mount point that links to the internal storage. Comparing this device with another device with CM the following folders are missing:

- /storage/emulated
- /storage/emulated/0
- /storage/emulated/legacy

These folders are empty (it should contain a folder `Android`):

- /sdcard
- /storage/sdcard0
- /mnt/sdcard

The folders and mount points for the external storage (SD card) exist but apps (except the file browser) cannot use them. These are folders that seems to be correct:

- /extSdCard
- /storage/sdcard1

In my opinion a shortcut to internal storage ist wrong or missing. Do you have any idea how I can fix the issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Seems that your repartitioned storage doesn't mount correctly, for some reason, perhaps due to partitioning error. Maybe try repartitioning it again? Or, if you're into some android-hacking, try to check it out trough adb to see if it's possible to mount any of those partitions and what errors might show up, that could give a clue of wgat's wrong. Or, check it out with adb, if you can mount those partitions, and what errors show up if you can't, that'll give a clue of what's wrong.

Comment: I already mounted from recovery. There came no error. But the mount points are removed at start. Is it possible that the used Pit file forgot defining the internal app storage?

Comment: 1.take a look at /etc/vold.fstab, if there is such a file (rom-dependant). 2.problem might be in the init.rc script, but it gets more complicated. More details on how to get to the insides of the init.rc here -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/11807215    Let me know if anything of this is helpful.

Comment: The FS wouldn't mount from properly if it was corrupted. By the way, did you try flashing another ROM?

Comment: I have not tried another ROM yet. The file /etc/vold.fstab does not exist. File /init.rc exists. Thanks for the link, I will have a look into.